# JavaMail: Null pointer exeception in BODYSTRUCTURE.parseParameters. Is it a bug?

Tags: nullpointerexception, jakarta-mail

I am trying to fetch messages using JavaMail 1.4.5 from an IMAP account and I get a null pointer exception in **BODYSTRUCTURE.parseParameters** method.

Looking the parseParameters code, I find this line

```
list.set(null, "DONE"); // XXX - hack
```

The problem is that the set method tries to call **.toLowerCase()** to the null value !!!

The response it is trying to parse is this:

```
* 1 FETCH (BODYSTRUCTURE (("TEXT" "PLAIN" ("CHARSET" "us-ascii") NIL NIL "7BIT" 55 4 NIL NIL NIL NIL)(("TEXT" "HTML" ("CHARSET" "us-ascii") NIL NIL "7BIT" 410 10 NIL NIL NIL NIL)("IMAGE" "JPEG" ("NAME" "image.jpg") "<53498286-6B3E-4AC8-8CA0-481152C80968@xxxx.it>" NIL "BASE64" 536628 NIL ("inline" ("FILENAME" "image.jpg")) NIL NIL) "RELATED" ("TYPE" "text/html" "BOUNDARY" "Apple-Mail=_56FA3EC6-FB02-4882-A1C5-487652E3B4E5") NIL NIL NIL) "ALTERNATIVE" ("BOUNDARY" "Apple-Mail=_CB164992-2501-4351-94D1-61CE7C8D90DC") NIL NIL NIL))
```

and, enabling the debug, I get those messages:

```
DEBUG IMAP: parsing BODYSTRUCTURE 
DEBUG IMAP: msgno 1 
DEBUG IMAP: parsing multipart 
DEBUG IMAP: parsing BODYSTRUCTURE 
DEBUG IMAP: msgno    1 
DEBUG IMAP: single part 
DEBUG IMAP: type TEXT 
DEBUG IMAP: subtype    PLAIN 
DEBUG IMAP: parameter name CHARSET 
DEBUG IMAP: parameter value    us-ascii
```

and then the NullPointerException

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.mail.internet.ParameterList.set(ParameterList.java:165)
at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.BODYSTRUCTURE.parseParameters(BODYSTRUCTURE.java:404)
at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.BODYSTRUCTURE.<init>(BODYSTRUCTURE.java:224)
at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.BODYSTRUCTURE.<init>(BODYSTRUCTURE.java:109)
at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.FetchResponse.parse(FetchResponse.java:158)
at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.FetchResponse.<init>(FetchResponse.java:67)
at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPResponse.readResponse(IMAPResponse.java:136)
at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.readResponse(IMAPProtocol.java:270)
at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.command(Protocol.java:313)
at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.fetch(IMAPProtocol.java:1529)
at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.fetch(IMAPProtocol.java:1521)
at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.fetchBodyStructure(IMAPProtocol.java:1221)
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.loadBODYSTRUCTURE(IMAPMessage.java:1307)
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.getDataHandler(IMAPMessage.java:623)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getContent(MimeMessage.java:927
```

Thanks to anyone that can help me !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've probably got a mix of JavaMail classes from two different versions of JavaMail.  Check your classpath for other instances of the javax.mail.* classes, perhaps in a j2ee.jar or javaee.jar.

Answer (score 14):

I finally discovered the cause of the problem.

I'm including Apache Cxf in my project.

Cxf includes a reference to geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec which overwrites some of the javamail classes.

Excluding the reference to geronimo, everything works correctly !

Comment: I spent a very long day looking for just this solution. Once I found your post it only took a half hour to get myself going. Thank you so much for taking the time to put your question and answer up here. It made a huge difference for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar (maybe the same) problem.

The problem was connected with mail server bug described in this Oracle FAQ [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#imapserverbug%22here%22).

The solution is to:

- fix the bug in your IMAP server
- OR use workaround described in Oracle FAQ

  ```
  // Get the message object from the folder in the
  // usual way, for example:
  MimeMessage msg = (MimeMessage)folder.getMessage(n);

  // Use the MimeMessage copy constructor to make a copy
  // of the entire message, which will fetch the entire
  // message from the server and parse it on the client:
  MimeMessage cmsg = new MimeMessage(msg);

  // The cmsg object is disconnected from the server so
  // setFlags will have no effect (for example).  Use
  // the original msg object for such operations.  Use
  // the cmsg object to access the content of the message.
  ```

or

```
// Get the message object from the folder in the
// usual way, for example:
MimeMessage msg = (MimeMessage)folder.getMessage(n);

// Copy the message by writing into an byte array and
// creating a new MimeMessage object based on the contents
// of the byte array:
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
msg.writeTo(bos);
bos.close();
SharedByteArrayInputStream bis =
        new SharedByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
MimeMessage cmsg = new MimeMessage(session, bis);
bis.close();

// The cmsg object is disconnected from the server so
// setFlags will have no effect (for example).  Use
// the original msg object for such operations.  Use
// the cmsg object to access the content of the message.
```

I've found this thanks to this Oracle forums [thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1591188?start=15&tstart=0)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for give me suggestion for this problem

I Add below dependency  in my project and everything working properly

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in one mac. I have tried setting it up in another mac. It worked like charm. 
I have cleaned up all Jenkins and started the instance using war again in a problematic machine (Used same war that worked on another machine). Have same Java version (1.8.0_211) in both the machines. I didn't bring in any project here, just tried checking poll mailbox trigger is working fine with dummy project. I get the same error. I have no clue where would be the difference in the classpath either since I didn't configure anything separately. Any pointers would be helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks for the answers Stefano Bertini and Bill Shannon!

In my case it was exluding it from cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:

```
<!-- CXF -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```